# Finding the marginal probability function of...

Tags: statistics, definite-integrals

The random number Y has a Poisson distribution with the parameter x. However, x itself is a random variable with the probability density function given by:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}e^{-x} &\text{ for } x \ge 0\\0 &\text{ elsewhere }\end{cases}$$ 
The joint probability of functions $X$ and $Y$ is:

$$f(x,y) = \frac {x^y}{y!} e^{-2x}$$ where $x \ge 0$ and $y = 0,1,2,...$(positive integers including 0)

I need to find the marginal probability function for $Y$. I think you're supposed to integrate over $f(x,y)$ with respect to x from 0 to infinity. If that's right, then I'm having trouble with the integral.

The answer is supposed to be $$f(y) = (\frac 12) ^{y+1}$$

Comment: What are the ranges of $x$ and $y$ in $f(x,y)$ ?

Comment: Oops, forgot to include that. It's x >= 0 and y = 0, 1, 2, ...(so just positive integers including 0 for y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $f(y) = \int_{x=0}^{\infty}f(x,y)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^y}{y!}e^{-2x}$
Now we substitute $2x=r, dx=dr/2$ and the integral becomes
\begin{equation}
f(y)=\frac{1}{y!}\frac{1}{2^{y+1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}r^ye^{-r}dr
\end{equation}
Now we observe that the integral is Gamma integral, i.e.,
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}r^ye^{-r}dr=\Gamma(y+1)=y! ~~\text{(Since}~ y ~\text{is integer)}
\end{align}
Hence we have
\begin{equation}
f(y)=\frac{1}{y!}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{y+1}.y!=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{y+1}~~\square
\end{equation}